# iOS - RestKit and sending a post request to the server?

Tags: iphone, ios, restkit

When I try to post an object using RestKit I get the following error.
"Cannot send a request that is loading or loaded without resetting it first."

What does it mean?
How can I reset a request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without posting a code, it is hard to say where the error is, but:
This error occurs, when either `_isLoading` or `_isLoaded` is set to `NO`. You could try to reset your request before sending it using `[myRequest reset];`.